# can't create object excel.application in vbscript

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, vbscript

This code runs in my local very well, but when I deploy it to server it says "Cant create object Excel.Application"

I tried to run it to another local computer and it runs well to. I don't know whats the problem. Please Help. Thank you

```
    Dim appXL As Excel.Application
    Dim wbXl As Excel.Workbook
    Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim raXL As Excel.Range

    ' Start Excel and get Application object.
    appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appXL.Visible = True
    ' Add a new workbook.
    wbXl = appXL.Workbooks.Add
    shXL = wbXl.ActiveSheet
    'Add table headers going cell by cell.
    Dim heads() As String = {"", "MONo", "PostingDate", "DocDate", "SBU", "Operation", "Resource", "TimeType", "StartDate", "StartTime", "EndDate", "EndTime", "NoofResources", "Remarks", "Quantity", "Rejects"}
    For head1 As Integer = 1 To 15
        shXL.Cells(1, head1).Value = heads(head1)
    Next
    Dim remarks1 As String = ""
    If lblrem.Text = "" Then
        remarks1 = Application("rec_remarks")
    Else
        remarks1 = lblrem.Text
    End If

    Dim body() As String = {"", txtmo.Text, lbleDate.Text, lbleDate.Text, Sap_routing, Operation, machinename, UCase(lblrem2.Text), lblsDate.Text, lblsTime.Text, lbleDate.Text, lbleTime.Text, no_ofres, remarks1, txtgoods.Text, txtrejects.Text}

        For body1 As Integer = 1 To 15
            shXL.Cells(2, body1).Value = body(body1)
        Next
    appXL.Visible = True
    appXL.UserControl = True
    ' Release object references.

    Dim sql_getsettings As String = "select * from path_settings where id = 1"
    Dim readSettings As New SqlCommand(sql_getsettings, conn)
    Dim settingsRow As SqlDataReader

    conn.Open()
    settingsRow = readSettings.ExecuteReader
    While settingsRow.Read
        strSetting = settingsRow(1)
    End While
    conn.Close()

    Dim myXlsFileName As String = "MO" & txtmo.Text & Format(Now, "yyyyMMdd") & Format(Now, "hhmmss")
    If Not File.Exists("C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\" & myXlsFileName & ".xls") Then
        wbXl.SaveAs(Filename:=strSetting & myXlsFileName & ".xls")
    End If

    raXL = Nothing
    shXL = Nothing
    wbXl = Nothing
    appXL.Quit()
    appXL = Nothing
    Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
        MsgBox(Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number)
```

when i try to publish my website in my local iis it gives me an error of Server Error in

```
'/' Application.
Cannot create ActiveX component.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: Cannot create ActiveX component.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

but when I try to run my program under visual studio it works well

Comment: Is Excel installed on the machine you are running the script?

Comment: yes its already install